# How to do comparisons on a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php

What is the best way to do comparisons in a multidimensional array? in this example I need to check if the indexes 1 and 2 of the internal arrays are repeated and if they are repeated bring the lowest monthly fee that is represented by index 3 of the internal array. What is holding me back is how am I going to compare an array of index 0 with index 1 and so on in a loop. Example:

```
[
    [
        0 = > 1,
        1 => test 1,
        2 => rj,
        3 => 1.500
    ],
    [
        0 => 2,
        1 => test 2,
        2 => sp,
        3 => 1.700
    ],
    [
        0 = > 3,
        1 => test 1,
        2 => rj,
        3 => 1.400
    ]
]
```

In this example I would return the last internal array, as it was verified that the index 0 and 2 are the same and its monthly fee is the lowest.

Comment: Does the key `1` represent the "unique ID" for each sub array?

Comment: yep, represents

Comment: Okay. The next question is, what do you want this function to look like? Do you want it to take a giant array as input and reduce it to a (potentially) smaller array where the sub-items are uniquely identified by array key `1`, and where duplicates are based on the lowest value of key `3`? Or, do you want to have a function where you say "from this array, give me the lowest for `test 1`?" Or, the most generic, "give me all of the `test 1` items, potentially sorted by a sub-key".

Comment: exactly the second option, from the main array return me the smallest that is equal to "test 1 " for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on those requirements, the following function should work. It should hopefully be pretty straightforward, but I added some comments to help a bit. The magic indexes are my least-favorite part.

```php
function find_smallest(array $data, string $key): ?array
{
    $smallest = null;
    foreach ($data as $subArray) {
        // Match on key
        if ($subArray[1] !== $key) {
            continue;
        }

        // If we didn't find anything yet, store this
        if (null === $smallest) {
            $smallest = $subArray;
            continue;
        }

        // We previously found this key, compare the third index
        if ($smallest[3] >= $subArray[3]) {
            $smallest = $subArray;
        }
    }

    return $smallest;
}
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments, I reworked this to find *all* of the smallest items, using the indexes at `1` and `2` to uniquify each item.

```php
function find_all_smallest(array $data): array
{
    // Used to form a unique key
    $key_delim = '!!';
    $all_smallest = [];
    foreach ($data as $sub_array) {
        $key = $sub_array[1].$key_delim.$sub_array[2];

        // If we didn't find anything yet, store this
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $all_smallest)) {
            $all_smallest[$key] = $sub_array;
            continue;
        }

        // We previously found this key, compare the third index
        if ($all_smallest[$key][3] >= $sub_array[3]) {
            $all_smallest[$key] = $sub_array;
        }
    }

    // Return the array parts, keys aren't needed
    return array_values($all_smallest);
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your time, but I think I expressed myself a little wrong, I'm sorry I don't speak English very well.

What I need is to check in all the sub arrays if they have the indices 1 and 2 exactly the same and if it is true to return the array whose index 3 is smaller, this logic I'm not able to put in the code because I'm locking in the logic in relation to the lops.

Comment: @WeslleyAraujo, hopefully that edit works for you